# UIScrollView only detecting swipes at bottom

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with a zoomed image view contained within it.  UIScrollView "contentSize" is about twice the height of the scrollview itself, enabling user to swipe the image up and down.  What I'm seeing is that the "touch zone" for the UIScrollView (where it detects swiping, and scrolls the image accordingly) is only at the very bottom of the UIScrollView.  Is there any property/method I can use to make the UIScrollView detect swipes throughout it's frame?

Answer (score 0):

if you want touch points inside scrollview tgen you can use following delegate method-

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```